# How to find a phone number in a Gmail message

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Several weeks ago, don't remember when exactly, a colleague sent me his phone number by email. Now I cannot find this email.

I tried to search for all messages by this colleague, but unfortulately, there are too many of them (there are some days in which we exchange tens of messages), and I just can't find the message with the phone.

Any idea, how can I find this message easily?

(Of course I can ask him to send again, but currently he is not online.)

Comment: You could narrow it by period, no attachment, part of the number (if you remember some of it), but I doubt you can do more than that.

Comment: Gmail doesn't support `regular expressions`, but someone made interesting tests, for example see [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/). I have no tested it, but it could be a way to explore.